# React app blank page on Netlify but works fine on my machine

Tags: reactjs, react-router, netlify

I have a router-based react app and when I run `npm run build` on my machine and serve it, it works fine
But when I deploy it to Netlify or Vercel, it doesn't work, just a blank page. When I view the source code, there is almost nothing there as well.

What is going on?

Comment: Have you checked if there are some logs errors or console errors when you hit the app.

Comment: No errors on console or logs